# Jquery not working in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have created a parallex scrolling effect in jquery on a static html/ css website, im now trying to copy this over to a wordpress theme.

This is how i imported the 2 javascript files (jquery-11.1.3.min.js, parallex.js)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'praid_load_js_files' );
function praid_load_js_files(){
     wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.11.3', true );
     wp_register_script( 'parallex', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/parallex.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

     //Adds to every page
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
     wp_enqueue_script( 'parallex' );
}
```

This is what is in my parllex file

```
  var pContainerHeight = $('.welcoming').height();

$(window).scroll(function(){

  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (wScroll <= pContainerHeight) {

    $('.welcomeText').css({
      'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /2 +'%)'
    });

    $('.welcoming').css({
      'transform' : 'translate(0px, -'+ wScroll /25 +'%)'
    });

  }
});
```

For some reason this works perfectly fine on a static html/ css page, but when its on word press it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: In the console are you getting any errors?

Comment: tried putting your code in `.ready`

Comment: @vinayakj what does that mean?

Comment: It means wrap your parralax code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ //parralax code here });`

Comment: @Jezzabeanz Great!, Thanks that worked

Comment: Points go to @vinayakj, I wouldn't have thought of that :)

Comment: yeah.. either do DOM manipulation inside `.ready` function or add your scripts at end of file. @Jezzabeanz upvote for explaining while I was away

Comment: @vinayakj Thank you :D

Comment: Also note that you don't have to enqueue jquery separately. By default, WordPress comes bundled with jquery.

Comment: @HareeshSivasubramanian so i dont need to add any jquery myself?

Comment: That's right. Try removing the line where you add jquery and see it for yourself. :)

Comment: @HareeshSivasubramanian great thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @vinayakj suggested in the comments, I wrapped the code in the parralex.js folder with

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //parralax code here });
```

And it worked.

PLUS: @HareeshSivasubramanian pointed out that I don't need to add the jquery myself as WordPress bundles it automatically.